# (s)applying subset (i.e. `[`) to various list structures

Tags: r, sapply

I've got a function from which I'd like to be able to return a quite relaxed set of structures:

```
str1 <- list(
          list(
            key = 123,
            data = "test"
          ),
          list(
            key = 987,
            data = "test"
          )
        )

str2 <- list(
          c(key = 123, data = "test"),
          c(key = 987, data = "test")
        )

str3 <- list(
          key = 123,
          data = "test"
        )

str4 <- c(key = 123, data = "test")
```

From these return values I'd like to be able to capture all key-values in a concise manner.

My attempt at a catch all solution was this:

```
sapply(str1, `[`, "key")
```

However, it only works for the nested structures(`str1` & `str2`). The others return `NA`.

I'm curious as to why I can do this:

```
str4["key"]
# 123
sapply(c(key = 1), `+`, 1)
# 2
```

...but not this?

```
sapply(c(key = 123), `[`, "key")
# NA
```

I'm not as interested in a workaround as I am to understand where I'm going wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand the difference between your two last lines of code, you can do:

```
> sapply(c(key = 123), function(i) browser())
Called from: FUN(X[[i]], ...)
Browse[1]> i
[1] 123
Browse[1]> i+1
[1] 124
Browse[1]> i['key']
[1] NA
```

You are basically try to extract the value by name on an ...unamed vector.

To solve your problem, a possible approach would be:

```
foo = function(str, key) {l=unlist(str); l[names(l) %in% key]}

#> foo(str1,'key')
#  key   key 
#"123" "987" 
#> foo(str2,'key')
#  key   key 
#"123" "987" 
#> foo(str3,'key')
#  key 
#"123" 
#> foo(str4,'key')
#  key 
#"123"
```

Comment: That's great, thank you!

Now it seems obvious as always, but I love the `browser()` trick, that's going to come in handy many times I'm sure.

Comment: it is the best way to debug and understand!